# Proving that $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n*n + 1}{n+2} $is divergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In my assignment I have to prove that the following sequence is divergent:

$$a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n*n + 1}{n+2} $$

I have an idea but I don't know if my solution is correct. Here it is:

Split into cases:

1. $L<0$
2. $L\ge 0$

I have to prove that for every $L$ $\in \Bbb R$ there is a $\epsilon$ such that for every $N \in \Bbb N$ there is $n>N$ such that $|a_{n}-L|\ge \epsilon$

Assume in contradiction that the sequence is convergent. Therefore:

$$\left| \frac{(-1)^n*n+1}{n+2}-L\right| < \epsilon$$

Assume that $L \ge 0$, we can get rid of the absolute value and write:
$$ \frac{(-1)^n*n+1}{n+2}-L < \epsilon =  \frac{(-1)^n*n}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+2}-L < \epsilon$$

This inequality is true if and only if:

$$(-1)^n*n +1 -\frac{L}{n+2} <\frac{\epsilon}{n+2}=(-1)^n*n<\frac{\epsilon}{n+2}+\frac{L}{n+2}-1$$

However, this inequality can be correct for odd values of n, OR for even values of n, thus we get a contradiction.

Similairly, I can prove the statement for $L<0$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You wrote "series" but your proof about limit of $a_n$

Comment: You need to remove all * signs and put in parentheses in various spots.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, then
$$
a_n = \frac{n+1}{n+2}
$$
and the limit is $1$. If $n$ is odd, then
$$
a_n=\frac{1-n}{n+2}
$$
and the limit is $-1$. You have found two subsequences with two different limits. Hence the sequence can't converge.

About your proof, be careful with those absolute values...

Answer (score 0):

multiplying denominator and numerator by $\frac{1}{n}$ we get $$\frac{(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{2}{n}}$$ thus we get $$1/n$$ and $$2/n$$ tends to zero for $n$ tends to infinity (1 tends to $1$ and $$(-1)^n$$ has no limit for $n$ tends to infinity, thus no limit exists.