# Understanding why $\frac{-n+1}{n+2}<-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to prove in $\epsilon,N$ language that $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}n+1}{n+2}$ is divergent. As I understand, we should prove that for every $L\in\mathbb{R}$ exists $\epsilon>0$ so for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n>N$ so $|a_n-L|\geq \epsilon$. The solution says:

> Let $L\in \mathbb{R}$. If $L\geq 0$ then we will choose $\epsilon=0.5$. We will check for which $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we get $\frac{-n+1}{n+2}<-\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> $$\frac{-n+1}{n+2}<-\frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow -2n+2<-n-2 \Leftrightarrow n>4$$

Why did the solution choose $-\frac{1}{2}$ (why the minus)? I understand from the solution that if $L\geq 0$ then $n$ is odd (but why?). I don't get those two things.

The questions was asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387944/proving-that-a-n-frac-1nn-1n2-is-divergent), but the solution there proves it using other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would first
see what the terms are
for even and odd $n$.

$\begin{array}\\
a_{2n}
&=\frac{(-1)^{2n}2n+1}{2n+2}\\
&=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\\
&=\frac{2n+2-1}{2n+2}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
a_{2n+1}
&=\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}(2n+2)}{2n+3}\\
&=-\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}\\
&=-\frac{2n+3-1}{2n+3}\\
&=-1+\frac{1}{2n+3}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\dfrac1{2n}
\le \dfrac14
$
for $n \ge 2$,
for such $n$,
$a_{2n} \ge \dfrac34$
and
$a_{2n+1} < -\dfrac34$
so
$|a_{2n}-a_{2n+1}|
\ge \dfrac32
$
which makes non-convergence
clear.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence tends to ±$1$. Therefore they choose $\epsilon$ to be $1/2$. if it were convergent to an $a$ there would be an $N$ so that all $a_n$ with $n>N$ so that $|a_n-a|<1/2$. Since the difference of consecutive terms tends to $2$ for $n \to \infty$ this can't the case.

Comment: I understand that but why $-0.5$?

Comment: It is smaller than half the difference of consecutive terms (for large n).

Comment: The difference is tends to 2. had they chosen 1 it would have (for example) been possible for the limit to be 0. since |an|<1

Comment: Still can't see it for some reason. I don't understand how formally they got to $-0.5$. why minus?

Comment: they show that every second term of the sequence is smaller -1/2 for n >4

Comment: The given proof is acctually not complete. You sill have to argue that after some term the othe $a_n$ are greater than +1/2,